# Unable to rebuild indexes for azure search

Tags: azure-search

Using sc8.2u3

I have the azure connection string setup and have enabled all azure configs. Disabled all lucene configs.

I haven't made any changes to the default config settings and also there are no custom fields created in my project.

When I select sitecore_master_index and rebuild the index, the pop says items added to index is around 500 and it stops there.

In the error log I see

> Job started: Index_Update_IndexName=sitecore_master_index|#Exception:
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. ---> System.AggregateException: One or
>   more errors occurred. --->
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.Exceptions.BadRequestException:
>   Error in the request URI, headers, or body --->
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.Exceptions.AzureSearchServiceRESTCallException:
>   {"error":{"code":"","message":"The request is invalid. Details:
>   parameters : The property 'content_item_image' does not exist on type
>   'search.documentFields'. Make sure to only use property names that are
>   defined by the type.\r\n"}}

The "content_item_image" is an image field.

But when I run it again, it shows a different field. So I stop and run again and it doesn't even add 1 item to the index in the status popup.

What could be wrong. Am I missing any step other than disabling and enabling those configs.

UPDATE:

I'm using the Azure free service and realize that it is only upto 3 indexes and 50 mb. Could this be the reason.

Comment: The message means that the field 'content_item_image' does not exist in the Azure Search index. However, I don't know how those fields are created by Sitecore. Is there any config file that you could check?

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues with rebuilding index in azure Sitecore will provide a hot fix package in my case.however, i would say to try to exclude this field or any other problematic field by using AddExcludedField .
having free service limitation could be the case here too.

Good luck

Comment: Naim, your issue was related to fieldname starting with digits "301", however Qwerty's problem might have different source. Excluding 'content_item_image' is an option, but I doubt that Sitecore's hotfix will solve this particular issue.

Comment: grg, I think you are referring to my post in the StackExchanage but it was not the whole story :) i had another issue with the text field size and media fields. I think there is a limitation in addition to a bug

Comment: @NaimAlkouki are you able to share the details of the Sitecore hotfix you received?